# Every simple Module is Cyclic

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

Can u help me prove that every simple module is cyclic? Ive already proved that a cyclic module is isomorphic to A quotiented by I ( I being a left ideal of A) using homomorphisms, but i cant seem to make any advance in proving this.Thx in advance.

Comment: Being simple, it will be generated by any nonzero element.

Comment: Alright, cause the subgroup generated by one element of the module will be a submodule and since there are only two and it isnt trivial it has to be M, so M is generated by that element. Thx

Comment: Although the idea of proof here is "simple", you might consider posting a self-answer (with good grammar and proper math notation) based on the Comment left you by @LordSharktheUnknown.  Otherwise if there is no longer an interest in this Question, you might want to self-delete it.

Answer (score 3):

Suppose $M$ is a simple left $R$-module. This means that $M\ne\{0\}$ and that the only submodules of $M$ are $\{0\}$ and $M$.

Now take $x\in M$, $x\ne0$ (which exists by assumption). Then $Rx$ is a submodule of $R$ and $x=1x\in Rx$. Thus $Rx\ne\{0\}$ and so $Rx=M$.

---

If your rings don't necessarily have an identity, the definition of simple module is slightly different. A left $R$-module $M$ is simple if

1. $RM\ne\{0\}$;
2. the only submodules of $M$ are $\{0\}$ and $M$.

By assumption, there exist $r\in R$ and $x\in M$ such that $rx\ne0$. Now $Rrx$ is a nonzero submodule of $M$, so $Rrx=M$ and, a fortiori, $Rx=M$.

Answer (score 0):

Let M be a simple module. Then the only submodules of M are the trivial submodule and M itself.
Suppose M is not cyclic, that is, it is not generated by any of its elements. Because M is a module, we know it is an additive subgroup and so the sets generated by each of its non-zero elements will form a subgroup of M but this contradicts our assumption that the only submodules of M are the trivial submodule and M itself

Comment: You are mixing subgroups and submodules.

Comment: Isn't every submodule a subgroup? I don't see anything wrong with the answer.

Comment: Every submodule is a subgroup, but not every subgroup is a submodule. So "this contradicts our assumption that the only subgroups of $M$ are the trivial subgroup and $M$ itself" is incorrect, there is no such assumption. The reasoning in itself is not wrong, but you have to replace each occurrence of "subgroup" by "submodule".

Comment: since we assumed the only submodules of M are the trivial submodule and M itself, doesn't it imply that those are the only subgroups of M?

Comment: No, it doesn't. For instance, $\mathbb{R}$ is of course a simple $\mathbb{R}$-module, so its only submodules (ie vector subspaces) are $\{0\}$ and $\mathbb{R}$ itself. But it has uncountably many non-trivial subgroups, with extremely complicated structures.

Comment: oh I get what you mean now. When I use subgroups in the answer, I mean additive subgroups. So does replacing subgroups with additive subgroups in the answer make sense?

Comment: thanks so much for the correction

Comment: No, changing to "additive subgroup" does not change the issue, it was already obvious that you meant that (what other kind of subgroups could there be in this situation). Please think about what I said with $\mathbb{R}$. Do you agree that $\mathbb{Z}$ is a non-trivial additive subgroup of $\mathbb{R}$, although $\mathbb{R}$ is a simple $\mathbb{R}$-module?